# Prove by induction: Let p1, · · · , pk be odd positive integers. Prove Sigma (p_i -1)/2 (from I=1 to k) ≡ ((p_1***p_k)-1)/2 (mod 2).

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove by induction: Let $p_1, \ldots , p_k$ be odd positive integers. Prove $$\sum_{I=0}^k \frac{p_i -1}{2} ≡ \frac{p_1\cdot \ldots \cdot (p_k -1)} {2}(\text{mod } 2)$$

I was able to verify the base case because when $p$ is odd and you let $p_1=2n_1+1$ and $p_2=2n_2+1$, you end up with $n_1 + n_2$ is congruent to $n_1+n_2 (\text{mod } 2)$, which is obviously true.

Then I assumed that the formula holds when $k=l$ and the goal is to prove that the formula holds when $k=l+1$.
Then I have when $k=l+1$,
$$(\frac{p_1-1}{2} + \frac{p_2-1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{p_l-1}{2} + \frac{p_{l+1} -1}{2} \text{ is congruent to  } \frac{p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot (p_l - 1)}{2} + \frac{p_{l+1} -1}{2} (\text{mod } 2) $$
I am not sure what to do from here to show that this is true.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: It seems to me it's a direct application of the induction hypothesis. What does it say? How can we apply it? If you're stuck, explain what you're tried and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to prove that $\frac{p_1+p_2+...+p_k-k}{2}-\frac{p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot... \cdot p_k -1}{2} \equiv 0 \ (mod \ 2) \iff A=p_1+p_2+...+p_k-k-(p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot... \cdot p_k -1) \equiv 0 \ (mod \ 4)$.  Now, suppose that exactly $n$ of numbers $p_1,p_2...,p_k$ have remainder $1$ when divided by $4$ and exactly $m$ of numbers $p_1,p_2...,p_k$ have remainder $3 \equiv (-1)$ when divided by $4$. Therefore $k=n+m$ and $$A = p_1+p_2+...+p_k-p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot... \cdot p_k +1-k\equiv a+(-b)-1^a\cdot(-1)^b+1-(a+b)=1-2b-(-1)^b .$$ If $b$ is even, then $1-2b-(-1)^b\equiv 1-0-1=0\ (mod \ 4)$, and if $b$ is odd, then $1-2b-(-1)^b\equiv 1-2+1=0\ (mod \ 4) \implies A \equiv 0 \  (mod \ 4)$